# masonry 2 column box using css float and clear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm want to make a 2 column div like google plus posts,before you ask:
1.cant use masonry.js because of it's absolute positioning and div expandablity
2.tried to use css columns and works good but the order is the problem
i want :
1 2
3 4
5 6
but css columns give me
1 4
2 5
3 6

i have  manages to do it with float and clear works awesome but there some gap that i remove it
this is my css that used :

```
.masonry .item:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f00;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}
.masonry .item:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #0020cc;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

this is the result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HntF0.jpg
can anyone help me with this ? any other option do i have to do this kine work ?
using bootstrap 3.3.5

Comment: Nope...this layout just isn't possible with CSS. That's why masonry.js exists.

Comment: @Paulie_D what can i do instead ? mentioned  that i cant use masonry.js !!

Comment: There is no CSS solution (AFAIK)...thats the point. Masonry.js (or similar) really is the answer here I suspect. It's probably just a matter of configuring it correctly.